# How to create an RSS feed and display it?

Tags: php, html, xml, rss, wysiwyg

On a website I am maintaining for a radio station they have a page that displays news articles. Right now the news is posted in an html page which is then read by a php page which includes all the navigation. I have been asked to make this into and RSS feed. How do I do this? I know how to make the XML file but the person who edits the news file is not technical and needs a WYSIWYG editor. Is there a WYSIWYG editor for XML? Once I have the feed how do I display it on my site? Im working with PHP on this site so a PHP solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that instead of trying to find a WYSIWYG for XML that I would let the news editor continue to upload the news as HTML. I ended up writing a php program to find the `<p>` and `</p>` tags and creating an XML file out of it.

Comment: Nevertheless, there is a WYSIWYG editor for XML: www.xopus.com

Answer (score 1):

Use [Yahoo Pipes!](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) : you don't need programming knowledge + the load on your site will be lower.  Once you've got your feed, display it on your site using a simple "anchor" with "image" in HTML.  You could consider piping your feed through [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com/) too.

And for the freeby: if you want to track your feed awareness data in rss, use my service [here](http://www.jldupont.com/page/services/feedburner).

Comment: At least tell the man what command in Pipes builds a feed from an HTML page, I can't remember myself.  I think http://www.dapper.net/dapp-factory.jsp is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: dapper is slow, dapper hangs... has it improved in the last year since I have last used it?

Comment: As for the down-vote (to whoever it was): guys, you do realize that down-voting an answer that provides a meaningful path to a solution is rude, right?

Comment: @Marshall: If "DaNieL" was so interested in his question, wouldn't he have done some follow-up?

Comment: all fair points, though I've found dapper sufficient for many projects.  my apologies for being rude, I'd change that downvote if I could but now it's too old.  I owe you one.  Just learning my way around here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you meaning that someone will insert the feed content by hand?

Usually feeds are generated from the site news content, that you should already have into your database.. just need a php script that extract it and write the xml.

Edit: no database is used.

Ok, now you have just 2 ways:

1. Use php regexp to get the content you need from the html page (or maybe [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/))
2. As you said, write the xml by hand and then upload it, but i havent tryed any wysiwyg xml editor, sorry.. [there are many on google](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=xml+wysiwyg+editor&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&aqi=g1g-m2&oq=xml+wysiwyg+editor&fp=8ec9ea851cee2c5b)

Comment: There is no database. Right now it is an html file that is written in a WYSIWYG editor and then uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Does that PHP site have a database back end? If so, the WYSIWYG editor posts into there then a special PHP file generates an RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following IBM page as a guide and it worked wonderfully:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-phprss/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [rssa.at](http://rssa.at) - just put in your URL and it'll create a RSS feed for you. You can then let people sign up for alerts (hourly/daily/weekly/monthly) for free, and access stats.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is consistent, you could just have them publish as normal and then scrape a feed.  There are programatic ways to do this for sure but http://www.dapper.net/dapp-factory.jsp is a nice point and click feed scraping service.  Then, use either MagpieRSS, SimplePie or Feed.informer.com to display the feed.